# Icing build-up & rain under roof valley with outside corner

Tags: roof

I've got an issue three roofers have been unable to come up with a solution for. My house has three gables meeting at outside corners over decorative consoles. This side had a small gutter with a downspout attached to the console when we bought the house. It was bent down at the corner & most of the water overflowed over the gutter edge. The first roofer recommended we remove it. He also never fixed the flashing over it. The last two winters I've had ice build up down the entire side of the house.

I doubt there was a gutter there originally, but there must have been something there to stall ice build-up.

The second roofer was supposedly working on a solution then they ghosted us. The third roofer was talking about a rain box & removing the console, which I'd prefer to keep.

I'd be perfectly happy with a solution that shot the water out away from the house or even the gutter with a splash guard on it.
[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I would agree with 3d roofer.

Comment: He first said it would have to be custom built & he wanted to pull the console off. Now he says he can't do it.

Comment: You refused to remove the console

Comment: You need a traditional gargoyle. Sitting on the console, spouting away. But really, that's just crummy roof design by whoever designed the house.

Comment: I think I've seen wires that you zigzag over the part of the roof near the edge.  There's some way of heating them up when needed.  Maybe that would solve it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, yes it is. The house was built in 1860 but the interior woodwork, layout & exterior make me think the house was extensively remodeled somewhere around the turn of the 20th century.

Comment: @Ruskes If we took the console off he'd have to put a block of wood there to support a rainbox. My understanding from him was he simply can't fashion a box for an outside corner, that's why I came here. I was hoping someone with some experience in Victorian/Edwardian architecture might have a solution.

Comment: So this is what he came up with. Waiting for the first rain to check it out. The downspout ends on the porch roof over a length of gutter on that section of porch. I have a feeling I'll need a splash guard on the second gutter. He replaced a small plastic one the first roofer put up & redirected the downspout. Now it'll empty out onto the porch roof down the valley.

Comment: The roofer put a larger gutter back up over the console with a splash fence. He also used a larger diameter downspout that ends over the porch that will let the water run down into a replaced gutter on that side of the porch. On the other valley he replaced the small plastic gutter the first roofer put up & rerouted the downspout to just run off the front of the porch in a valley on that side rather that run through a diagonal section over the the aforementioned gutter. Waiting for the rain to see how it works out.